# Dismiss current navigation controller when clicked tab bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have got a tab bar controller and in home view controller i have a navigation controller.

-Tab Bar Controller

-- HomeVC

--- VC1 navigation push -> VC2

In VC1 navigation bar is not hidden but inside VC2 is hidden. And im controlling it with viewwillappear and viewwilldisappear.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

But turning back to the VC1 without swipe, I mean clicking tab bar homeVC icon hides navigation bar. I want to dismiss or pop current viewcontroller and turn back to VC1.

Comment: So you want to get back on Top view controller of tab when tab change?

Comment: why, you can hide navigaitonBar from vc2 in `viewDidAppear()` and unhide in vc1 `viewDidAppear()` try this and let me know its working or not

Comment: In VC1  I set navigationBar.isHidden = false in viewWillAppear it is done.

Comment: @Alper when clicking tabbar you want to back onto Top viewcontroller VC1 right?

Comment: @Jaydeep yes there is no problem about turnign back to VC1, but when I turn back to VC1 I want to dismiss VC2 or I dont know if it dismisses automatically

Comment: @Alper you want to dismiss or pop back to VC1?

Comment: @Jaydeep popback to VC1 actually. I mean I dont want to VC2 work background.

Comment: @Alper So you have to do is every time when you change tab you have to pop to root Viewcontroller.

Comment: @Jaydeep like Instagram. In home tab bar, you go someone's profile but when you click again home tab bar it turns to the feed. Mine is too. But I dont know if VC2 is working on background or not.

Comment: @Alper Check my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this by `popToRootViewController` of `UINavigationController`. you have to handle this in `tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)` method of `UITabBarDelegate`.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if let rootView = self.viewControllers!["Index of VC1 Controller"] as? UINavigationController {
        rootView.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I have deleted viewWillAppear inside VC1 and wrote your code in tabbar controller, I think it worked :)